# Why is [coding-standards] a synonym of [code-style]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

While [code-style](/questions/tagged/code-style) is a quite well-defined tag, I'm surprised to see that [coding-standards](/questions/tagged/coding-standards) is actually a synonym for it.

I'd expect [coding-standards](/questions/tagged/coding-standards) to relate to *actual standards*—so formal documents like CERT secure coding, MISRA, etc. These two tags look like a different pair of socks to me.

Comment: Why is it a synonym? **Because that's how 99% of people who asked/tagged questions on SO were using it.** Could you make a case that they're actually different? Sure, but that won't change the typical use scenarios, which is what tag synonyms are intended to address. What tags do those types of questions use now?

Comment: While I agree with what @Cody says, I think we've gone a little crazy on the synonyms for this tag. If I'm searching for *[coding-standards]*, I'm not sure I want to see questions about *[spaghetti-code]*.